# How to set 2 EditText views below each other? What am i doing wrong?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I am a beginner and do not understand the android package in depth

```
package com.example.shiben.javaproject;

import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //creating relativelayout
        RelativeLayout app_layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

        //Objects for layout
        Button login_button = new Button(this);
        EditText uname = new EditText(this);
        ImageView logo = new ImageView(this);
        logo.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.oil));
        EditText pwd = new EditText(this);


        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams login_button_position = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
                (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams uname_position = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
                (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams pwd_position = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
                (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams logo_position = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
                (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        //adding objects to layout
        app_layout.addView(login_button, login_button_position);
        app_layout.addView(uname, uname_position);
        app_layout.addView(logo, logo_position);
        app_layout.addView(pwd, pwd_position);

        //standard line of code to convert dp to pixels for objects
        Resources r = getResources();
        int px = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 300,
                r.getDisplayMetrics());

        //position and style
        uname_position.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, login_button.getId());
        pwd_position.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, uname.getId());
        uname_position.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        uname_position.setMargins(0,0,0,50);
        pwd_position.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        pwd_position.setMargins(0,0,20,50);
        login_button.setText("Login");
        login_button.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        login_button_position.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        login_button_position.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        logo_position.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
        logo_position.setMargins(0,0,0,50);
        pwd.setWidth(px);
        uname.setWidth(px);



        //assigning id to objects
        login_button.setId(1);
        uname.setId(2);
        pwd.setId(3);

        //app start page
        setContentView(app_layout);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you should define your layout in xml and then load it with java - see how other people do it - you find plenty of examples on github (like this: https://github.com/codepath/intro_android_demo )

Comment: @AdamSzewera Thank you for the suggestion
isn't it possible to handle layout view and logic all on the java file rather than creating xml files separately ?

Comment: sure, but since you stated that you're a beginner in Android, I suggested to use xml layout.
Using XML and java in android is the most common way. Using just Java for both logic and layout is a waste of time. XML definition of the UI is there for a reason.
I mean "the right way" is to define the UI in XML and use java for logic, unless you need to do specific things like animations, or complex transformations, you don't use java for UI.
This is a very broad answer, but being an Android dev myself I don't use java for building UI that often.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @AdamSzewera